# Blog post not showing title

Tags: posts, title, theme-twenty-eleven

When on my main site NewMediaNook.wordpress.com, one particular post does not show a title (see image below). When I am on just that one post, the title appears, and all other titles appear when on the main site...but that one does not show up.

All browsers look the same, regardless of login status.

Can I just add it in with code??
(I just don't want to risk extra code to junk it up or potentially show the title twice in some random spots).

Sorry, I'm new at WordPress, so I'm not sure what other information is needed. But all help is appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because you have set the post format of that entry to `link`, and for that post format TwentyEleven does not show the post title:

```
.format-link .entry-title {
    display: none;
}
```

Solution: Use another post format (`standard` for example) or another theme.

[image]